# Agave dependency error

Tags: makefile, fedora

I am trying to install Agave under Fedora, but I got this error:

> configure: error: gnome-doc-utils >= 0.3.2 not found

I tried to compile and install the gnome-doc-utils from [this page](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/gnome/gnome-doc-utils.html), but i still got this error,and when i try the

> yum list installed gnome-doc-utils*

command, I can't find the package. Do I have to register the package after installing? I don't think I have a error for the make install, because I don't see any the text error in the process, or I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In general, package managers (tools like `yum`) don't know that something has been installed on your machine unless it was installed as a package. If an agave package for Fedora exists, I would suggest using that instead of compiling from source.

Comment: someone on the irc channel told me that it is not included with fedora 16 due to compiling problem, that is why i am trying to compile it.so this could be that i have installed the gnome-doc-utils-0.20.2 and for some reason the agave still can't compile it?

Comment: Did you separately install `gnome-doc utils`, or is it included with Agave?

Comment: Did you use the package manager to install `gnome-doc utils`, or compile it form source? Also, did you install that specific version of `gnome-doc utils`?